# Read value of a control in one window from another window in WPF MVVM application

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm creating a small WPF application. I have to follow MVVM pattern to which I'm new.

I have two views(A,B) and two viewmodels.

This is my scenario, I have a radiobutton in window A. After checking the radiobutton, I click next in window A. The event will close Window A and open window B.

In the constructor of viewmodel of window B, I need to know if Radiobutton in window A is checked or not. How do I do this?

Comment: You could pass the radiobutton state to the window B constructor.

Answer (score 0):

If you "have to follow MVVM pattern", you "have to" do the following.

First, you need create two ViewModels, for view A and for view B (but if you want - you can left only one ViewModel). For ViewModelA you should create **[ICommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.icommand(v=vs.110).aspx)** property, that you bind with **next** button, and bool property **IsChecked**. ViewModelB should either contain a constructor, which will accept the bool parameter, or a property, which should be updated before view B will show.

Here the example of how it can be accomplished:

```
public class ViewModelA : ViewModelBase
{
    public ViewModelA()
    {
        _nextCommand = new Cmd(this);
    }
    public ICommand NextCommand { get { return _nextCommand; } }

    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get { return _isChecked; }
        set
        {
            _isChecked = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("IsChecked");
        }
    }
    private ICommand _nextCommand;
    private bool _isChecked;
}
```

In the *.xaml view for A you should have the following:

```
<RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsChecked}" />
<Button Content="Next" Command="{Binding Path=NextCommand}" />
```

Please note: **[DataContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.datacontext(v=vs.110).aspx)** for that view should be of type **ViewModelA**.

For ViewModelB:

```
public class ViewModelB : ViewModelBase
{
    private bool _isAChecked;
    public bool IsAChecked
    {
        get
        {
            return _isAChecked;
        }
        set
        {
            _isAChecked = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("IsAChecked");
        }
    }
}

public class Cmd : ICommand
{
    ViewModelA _vmA;
    public Cmd(ViewModelA vmA)
    {
        _vmA = vmA;
    }
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        var vmB = new ViewModelB();
        vmB.IsAChecked = _vmA.IsChecked;
        // after that create ViewB, and set its DataContext to vmB
    }
}

public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Instead of creating for each command its class, you can see the examples of the **[RelayCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn237302.aspx)**, or **[DelegateCommand](http://wpftutorial.net/DelegateCommand.html)**, which are approximately do the same things.